# Regex: To match a pattern not in starting of a line

Tags: regex

I want use regex to match a pattern (exp: double slash), that is not at the starting of a line.
From the example below, I would like to match the double slash of line 5 and line 7 only. I am new to regex, hope to get some help from pro here :) Thanks in advance

```
// This is line 1
// This is line 2
// This is line 3

                 Something // This is line 5

                 Something // This is line 7
// This is line 8
```

Comment: Try playing with a Regex designer such as http://www.regexr.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex with negative lookahead:

```
(?!^)\/{2}
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/bA6dY4/1)

`(?!^)` is negative lookahead that means don't match `//` at line start.

Comment: Thanks man, this really help. By the way, can this regex work for vim in unix too? :)

Comment: `vim` has different regex syntax for negative lookahead that I can't recall since its been long time since I used it. You may need to check vim docs for that.